# Numpy: Randomly select 9/10 elements and save remaining

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a custom function that takes an array of 10 elements as the input and then randomly selects 9 elements to save in one object, and the remaining element in another object.
I have written a function that works if all elements are unique:

```
x = np.arange(10)

def myfunc(x):
    X = np.random.choice(x, 9, replace=False)
    y = np.setdiff1d(x, X)
    return X, y
    
X, y = myfunc(x)

print(X)
print(y)
```

This approach works as long as the elements are unique, but I'm afraid setdiff won't do the job if the array happens to have duplicate values.
Is there a more elegant way to assign the remaining value to its own object?

Comment: Why don't you just randomly select one element and then delete it from original array?

Comment: How would I do that? it is important that I don't change the input array, but create new objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
from random import randint

x = np.arange(10)

def myfunc(x):
    index = randint(0, len(x) - 1)
    return np.concatenate((x[:index], x[:index+1])), x[index]
    
X, y = myfunc(x)

print(X)
print(y)
```

Comment: this unfortunately does not work as intended, X does not always have length 9 and and also repeatedly samples elements from x. y is also included in X.